# Youtube API Quota Limit Exceeding Too Fast (100x)

Tags: google-api, youtube-data-api

I am currently using the "Search by Keyword" sample at the following link. I am implementing this solution in NET Core (c#), utilising the Youtube API.

The issue I am having is that my used quota allowance, which is 10,000 queries per day, is increasing by 100x each time this code is executed.

I have tried limiting my search to only Videos and not Playlist/Channels using the following code:

```
searchListRequest.Type = "video";
```

I am using API authentication, not OAuth. I have restricted the usage of the API key on the developer console also.

I have ensured that the following line is only called once and not inside a loop etc:

```
// Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

The sample is provided at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, each call has a "Quota Cost". So one call does not necessarily equal one of your quota amount.

There is a calculator at the following link:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost

Hope this helps someone.